# Meteor: load collection in 'rendered' function

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor app I have this `rendered` function which needs to access a specific collection. Assume I have a collection ToDos

```
ToDos = new Meteor.Collection('todos');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('todos');
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Meteor.publish('todos', function () {
            return ToDos.find({});
        });
    });
}
```

Now in a rendered function I want to do something like this

```
Template.todos.rendered = function () {
    var todo = ToDos.findOne({...});

    if (todo) {
        $('[datepicker]').datepicker('setDate', todo.date);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that when `rendered` is called, `todo` is `undefined` and this function is only called once. Is there a fix for this ? Can `Deps.autorun` help ?. If yes, how ?

On the other hand, if I could just listen for the `ToDos` only I could update the datepicker there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a potentially annoying problem in Meteor.  Essentially, whilst the handle that your `Meteor.subscribe` call returns has a `ready` method which will tell you if the collection is ready or not, usually your `rendered` callbacks will have run by the time it returns `true`, so it's not very useful in this case.  You can use the `onReady` callback in your subscribe call in some cases, and it's even possible to plug into a template's data context from elsewhere if you know the template instance exists and do anything you could in the `rendered` callback, but this would probably be a very messy way of dealing with the problem you present (because if there was ever a case in which the collection *was* ready before the DOM had been rendered it would fall down).

**SOLUTION:**
As is often the case, [iron router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) is the best solution here, as it allows each route to have a `waitOn` callback, which you can use to specify which subscriptions need to be `ready()` before the page begins to render (although you can wait on anything with a `ready` callback, not just subscriptions).  That way, you always know that your `Collection.find` will return what you're expecting when your `rendered` callbacks first run.

Comment: iron route sounds a good solution. Do you know a good place where I can find some solid documentation on this subject ?

Comment: The github link I posted has good documentation on it, and [this](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) is also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you've got a simple app with only one page**

A possible implementation with deps

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('todos');
        Deps.autorun(function(e) {
            var todo = ToDos.findOne({...});
            var $picker = $('[datepicker]');
            if (!!todo && !!$picker) {
                $picker.datepicker('setDate', todo.date);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Meteor renders the template first and **then** grabs data.  So when the data changes you have to go and set your data picker.

[Collection.observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) might be of interest to you too.  You can get a callback every time data is added, changed, deleted, etc.

```
var todo = ToDos.find({...});
var handle = todo.observeChanges({
    added: function (id, todo) {
        // do stuff on added
    },
    removed: function () {
        // do stuff on removed
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do: `var cursor = ToDos.find({}); cursor.observe(function() {..});` inside the rendered function nothing ever happens. Note that in my case the data doesn't change, It needs to be initially loaded

Comment: I looks like your observe syntax isn't quite right.  I edited my comment to the syntax.  Should be similar to Observe